# 2D Game - Turn-based RPG using MVC pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, 2d-games

I'd like to make a 2D game in Java using MVC pattern but I have some issues concerning the battles.

There are two groups, one of heroes and one of monsters.The player can control the first one.
My game is turn-based : I'd like to select one character at a time, ask the player the action to use, its target, and finally execute the action. However I can't seem to adjust this sequence of commands with the MVC pattern.

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: I guess your question fits better here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The controler and viewer ask the model what state it is in, if in combat the view shows a combat GUI, the controller lets input toggle through heroes and their spells/attacks. That is the simplest way I can imagine doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC pattern does not solve your object model design. It is a good start and can be used to produce a layered architecture, where your Model is separate from the View. But your design problem is within the model itself - you need to create an Object Design for this and probably use other Design patterns.

You may want to have a look at the **[Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)** as it helps to abstract Actions/Commands and makes handling them easier.